# Having Difficulty With Sharpe Ratio and Optimal Portfolio

Tags: portfolio-management, sharpe-ratio

[image: Sharpe image]

I have begun by using such equations as:

[image]

By finding the $Rp$ and $\sigma p$ with the weighted values, and then I followed the equation using a value of $.02$ for the fixed asset, $rf$, but this comes up with a value that is not correct. The answer apparently is $0.5813$, but I cannot get to this value. My values are in the $0.300$ range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0.5813 is correct. I won't post the formulas here given it is to basic. 
I am attaching picture with all the numbers you need. 
If you have a question on how any of those numbers is computed just ask, but should be very straightforward.

[image]